# Variable scope and namespaces when using import *

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a better understanding of python imports and namespaces. Take the example of a module testImport.py:

```py
# testImport.py
var1 = 1

def fn1():
    return var1
```

if I import this like this:

```py
from testImport import *
```

I can inspect `var1`

```py
>>> var1
1
```

and `fn1()` returns

```py
>>> fn1()
1
```

Now, I can change the value of var1:

```py
>>> var1 = 2
>>> var1
2
```

but `fn1()` still returns 1:

```py
>>> fn1()
1
```

This is different to if I import properly:

```py
>>> import testImport as t
>>> t.var1 = 2
>>> t.fn1()
2
```

What's going on here? How does python 'remember' the original version of `var1` in `fn1` when using `import *`?

Comment: When you use `import *` you are copying the references to every variable. Each module will have it's own version. This is a major reason why you don't want to use `import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How `from .. import ..` works

The statement

```
from module import value
```

can basically be rewritten as

```
import module
value = module.value
del module # Note: this just deletes the reference to `module`. Modules are never garbage collected.
```

Thus, the attribute `value` is a copy of `module.value`.

## Function scopes and module namespaces

If you define a function, it will be placed in a scope:

```
def g():
    a = 2
    def f():
        print(a)
    return f
print(g()())
```

The function `f` is bound to the namespace inside `g` so it can access `a` and print `2`.

It's the same with modules. Each module has it's own scope just like a function. So functions can access variables inside their own module. Variables in different scopes, like in your case `var1` won't effect it.

## Why the last example works

However, you can directly modify the scope like in your last example. If you use

```
import module
```

The variable `module` will actually refer to the scope of the contents of that module. So you can change variables there as you wish and they will effect functions and also other files that reference that module.

Answer (score 1):

The modules are *two seperate namespaces*. You are creating a new set of variables when you do:

```
from testImport import *
```

When you import properly, and mutate the module namespace directly,

```
import testImport as t
t.var1 = 2
```

that modifies the globals the function sees because *the module global namespace is the module object namespace*. They are one and the same!